# How can I setup CMS (Contest Management System) on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, server

I’m trying to setup CMS (which can be found here [here](https://cms-dev.github.io) ) on Ubuntu 16.04 32bit.
I’m a complete noob when it comes to Ubuntu so I would like to ask you guys and gals if someone can guide me through this I would be very grateful.
Also please could you provide a lot of details from A to Z because I don't think I can solve a problem on my own when it comes to Ubuntu.

Comment: What problems did you have with the docs?
 https://cms.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3/Installation.html

Answer (score 2):

Copied straight from [the official installation instructions](https://cms.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3/Installation.html):

> ## Installation
>
> ### Dependencies and available compilers
>
> […]
>
> #### Ubuntu
>
> On Ubuntu 16.04, one will need to run the following script to satisfy all dependencies:
>
> ```sh
> # Feel free to change OpenJDK packages with your preferred JDK.
> sudo apt-get install build-essential openjdk-8-jre openjdk-8-jdk fpc postgresql postgresql-client gettext python2.7 iso-codes shared-mime-info stl-manual cgroup-lite
>
> # Only if you are going to use pip/virtualenv to install python dependencies
> sudo apt-get install python-dev libpq-dev libcups2-dev byaml-dev libffi-dev python-pip
>
> # Optional
> sudo apt-get install nginx-full php7.0-cli php5-fpm phppgadmin texlive-latex-base a2ps gcj-jdk haskell-platform
> ```
>
> ### Preparation steps
>
> Download [CMS](https://github.com/cms-dev/cms/releases/download/v1.3.rc0/v1.3.rc0.tar.gz) 1.3.rc0 from GitHub as an archive, then extract it on your filesystem. You should then access the cms folder using a terminal.
>
> > **Warning:** If you decided to `git clone` the repository instead of downloading the archive, and you didn’t use the `--recursive` option when cloning, then *you need* to issue the following command to fetch the source code of the sandbox:
> >
> > ```sh
> > git submodule update --init
> > ```
>
> In order to run CMS there are some preparation steps to run (like installing the sandbox, compiling localization files, creating the `cmsuser`, and so on). You can either do all these steps by hand or you can run the following command:
>
> ```sh
> sudo ./prerequisites.py install
> ```
>
> This script will add you to the `cmsuser` group if you answer `Y` when asked. If you want to handle your groups by yourself, answer `N` and then run:
>
> ```sh
> sudo usermod -a -G cmsuser <your user>
> ```
>
> You can verify to be in the group by issuing the command:
>
> ```sh
> groups
> ```
>
> Remember to logout, to make the change effective.
>
> > **Warning:** Users in the group `cmsuser` will be able to launch the `isolate` program with root permission. They may exploit this to gain root privileges. It is then imperative that no untrusted user is allowed in the group `cmsuser`.
>
> ### Installing CMS and its Python dependencies
>
> There are a number of ways to install CMS and its Python dependencies:
>
> #### Method 1: Global installation with pip
>
> There are good reasons to install CMS and its Python dependencies via pip (Python Package Index) instead of your package manager (e.g. apt-get). For example: two different Linux distro (or two different versions of the same distro) may offer two different versions of `python-sqlalchemy`. When using pip, you can choose to install a *specific version* of `sqlalchemy` that is known to work correctly with CMS.
>
> Assuming you have `pip` installed, you can do this:
>
> ```sh
> sudo pip2 install -r requirements.txt
> sudo python2 setup.py install
> ```
>
> This command installs python dependencies globally. Note that on some distros, like Arch Linux, this might interfere with the system package manager. If you want to perform the installation in your home folder instead, then you can do this instead:
>
> ```sh
> pip2 install --user -r requirements.txt
> python2 setup.py install --user
> ```
>
> ### Method 2: Virtual environment
>
> > **Warning:** An alternative method to perform the installation is with a [virtual environment](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/), which is an isolated Python environment that you can put wherever you like and that can be activated/deactivated at will. The tool you need in order to create a virtual environment is called `virtualenv`, and can be installed by looking for `virtualenv` using your Linux distribution's package manager. For example:
>
> - Ubuntu 14.x: [python-virtualenv](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/python-virtualenv).
> - Ubuntu 16.x: [virtualenv](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/virtualenv).
>
> Once you installed `virtualenv`, you will need to create a virtual environment somewhere in your filesystem. For example, let's assume that you decided to create it under your home directory (as `~/cms_venv`):
>
> ```sh
> virtualenv -p python2 ~/cms_venv
> ```
>
> To activate it:
>
> ```sh
> source ~/cms_venv/bin/activate
> ```
>
> After the activation, the `pip` command will *always* be available (even if it was not available globally, e.g. because you did not install it). In general, every python command (python, pip) will refer to their corresponding virtual version. So, you can install python dependencies by issuing:
>
> ```sh
> pip install -r requirements.txt
> python setup.py install
> ```
>
> > Note: Once you finished using CMS, you can deactivate the virtual environment by issuing:
> >
> > ```sh
> >  deactivate
> > ```
>
> #### Method 3: Using `apt-get` on Ubuntu
>
> > **Warning:** It is usually possible to install python dependencies using your Linux distribution's package manager. However, keep in mind that the version of each package is controlled by the package mantainers and could be too new or too old for CMS. **On Ubuntu, this is generally not the case** since we try to build on the python packages that are available for the current LTS version.
>
> To install CMS and its Python dependencies on Ubuntu, you can issue:
>
> ```sh
> sudo python setup.py install
> sudo apt-get install python-setuptools python-tornado python-psycopg2 python-sqlalchemy python-psutil python-netifaces python-crypto python-tz python-six python-beautifulsoup python-mechanize python-coverage python-mock python-requests python-werkzeug python-gevent python-bcrypt python-chardet patool
>
> # Optional.
> sudo apt-get install python-yaml python-sphinx python-cups python-pypdf2
> ```
>
> ### Running CMS non-installed
>
> To run CMS without installing it in the system, you need first to build the prerequisites:
>
> ```sh
> ./prerequisites.py build
> ```
>
> There are still a few steps to complete manually in this case. First, add CMS and isolate to the path and create the configuration files:
>
> ```sh
> export PATH=$PATH:./isolate/
> export PYTHONPATH=./
> cp config/cms.conf.sample config/cms.conf
> cp config/cms.ranking.conf.sample config/cms.ranking.conf
> ```
>
> Second, perform these tasks (that require root permissions):
>
> - create the `cmsuser` user and a group with the same name;
> - add your user to the `cmsuser` group;
> - set isolate to be owned by root:cmsuser, and set its suid bit.
>
> For example:
>
> ```sh
> sudo useradd cmsuser
> sudo usermod -a -G cmsuser <your user>
> sudo chown root:cmsuser ./isolate/isolate
> sudo chmod u+s ./isolate/isolate
> ```
>
> ### Updating CMS
>
> As CMS develops, the database schema it uses to represent its data may be updated and new versions may introduce changes that are incompatible with older versions.
>
> To preserve the data stored on the database you need to dump it on the filesystem using `cmsDumpExporter` **before you update CMS** (i.e. with the old version).
>
> You can then update CMS and reset the database schema by running:
>
> ```sh
> cmsDropDB
> cmsInitDB
> ```
>
> To load the previous data back into the database you can use `cmsDumpImporter`: it will adapt the data model automatically on-the-fly (you can use `cmsDumpUpdater` to store the updated version back on disk and speed up future imports).